# call __str__ inside a class? python 3.X

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Im trying to develop a Elevator simulator. When the lift move up a floor , i want to be able to display how many customers are waiting , in lift, floor ect. (one string)

When i call `self.__str__()` inside a while loop , it just goes in but doesn't return the string to the screen.

Can somebody give us a help out a bit
Thanks

Comment: I think you want `print(self)` -- `self.__str__()` will automatically be called if it exists.  If it doesn't, `self.__repr__()` will be called if it exists then `object`'s `__repr__()` (which always exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling `__str__` directly. It should be called like str(object) or let it automatically convert.

Also that just returns a readable string representing the object. It does not print it. You would want to do.

```
print(self.__str__())
```

or just

```
print(self)
```

Comment: Thanks , still new to python , This is what i was looking for. Works perfectlly

Comment: No problem, hit the up vote if it helped you.

Comment: And mark answer accepted so additional reviewers know this already has a good answer.